# Why the result is not included?

Tags: trigonometry

If i have this exercise:

$\tan(\alpha) = 0$, the solution is when the $\sin(a) = 0$, that is in $0°$ and $180°$, because $\tan = \sin/\cos$

So the solution must be: $\alpha_1 = 0 + \pi k$, $\alpha_2 = \pi + \pi k$

But according to symbolab, the unique solution is the $\alpha_1$, so why $\alpha_2$ is incorrect?

Comment: Check the answer again: It should be just $\pi k$, since $\tan$ has a period of $\pi$.

Comment: also it is bad form to mix degrees and radians $180 = \pi$.

Comment: I already edited, but why the answer $\pi + \pi k$ isn't included?

Comment: There's no need for $a_2$, since it's subsumed by $a_1$. In other words, any value from $a_2$ can be realized using $a_1$ with $k$ adjusted. Explicitly, $\pi+\pi k = \pi(k+1)$.

Comment: You mean to say something like:

$ 0 + 2 \pi k $, is the same as: $ 2 \pi + 2 \pi k $

Comment: The set of solutions described by your $\alpha_1$ are $\{\dots,\pi\cdot(-1),\pi\cdot 0, \pi\cdot 1, \pi\cdot 2,\pi\cdot 3,\dots\}$.  The set of solutions described by your $\alpha_2$ are $\{\dots,\pi+\pi\cdot(-1),\pi+\pi\cdot 0,\pi+\pi\cdot 1,\pi+\pi\cdot 2,\dots\}$ which you notice after simplification is exactly the same set as the first.  That doesn't make it "incorrect", just *redundant*.

Comment: @Mattiu `0+2πk, is the same as: 2π+2πk` No, of course, but $\,\{k \pi \mid k \in \Bbb Z\} = \{\pi + k \pi \mid k \in \Bbb Z\}\,$.

Comment: The answer is neither  $0+\pi k$  nor $\pi+\pi k,$ but , as in the previous comment by dxiv,  the answer is "$\tan a=0 \iff a\in \{\pi k:k\in \Bbb Z\}."$...... $\pi k$  is a number. The solution is not a number. It is an infinite set of numbers.

Answer (score 0):

Note that $$\pi k $$ also covers $$\pi + \pi k $$ because  $$\pi + \pi k = \pi ( k+1) $$ and as $ k$ runs over integers, it covers $k+1$ as well.